# Flutter: Change theme data depending on mobile/tablet device type

Tags: flutter

I have a requirement to change the text height across the app if the user is on a tablet device. The simplest way would be to adjust the TextStyle height values when setting up our TextTheme in our MaterialApp. Currently we determine whether the user is on a tablet by checking if `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 600`. So something like:

```
textTheme: TextTheme(
                  body1: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'roboto',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 600
                          ? 1.15
                          : 1.3),
```

This check unfortunately doesn't work at the time when we're setting our theme up, as we get the error:

> MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a
>   MediaQuery. No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the
>   context that was passed to MediaQuery.of(). This can happen because
>   you do not have a WidgetsApp or MaterialApp widget (those widgets
>   introduce a MediaQuery), or it can happen if the context you use comes
>   from a widget above those widgets.

How should I go about checking for device type when setting up ThemeData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used was to wait for the first page to build, use its context to determine the device width, then 'pass' the result back to the MaterialApp by listening for state changes using the bloc pattern.